# How to access items from ndarray with dtype=object

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I access data inside a numpy array with `dtype=object`?

```
b = numpy.array({"a":[1,2,3]}, dtype=object)
```

The following raises an `IndexError`.

```
print(b["a"])
```

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you passed in the dict to `numpy.array()` without putting it in a list, this is a zero-dimensional array. To index into a zero-dimensional array, you can use `b.item()` to access the element inside. For completeness, to access the data in the `"a"` key in your dictionary, you can use this.

```py
>>> b.item()["a"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks ! I looked up https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html but didn't realize that item() method would let me access the 0-dim array. There is no way to access it using square brackets or dot notation.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I believe you can also index into the 0-dim array by slicing with a 0-tuple like `b[()]["a"]`